# How do I get named sub parameters that are also fast?

Tags: perl

Parameters to perl subs are passed in @_. To make my programs easier to read, I've always used this pattern to get named parameters:

```
sub foo1 {
    my ($bar, $baz) = @_;
    do_something($bar,$baz);
}
```

but it causes `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` to be *copied*. If I were to access `$_[0]` directly instead of accessing `$bar` in the above pattern, I have call-by-value/alias access to the callers parameters with the usual caveats of call-by-reference, but it is much faster (see demo below).

I'm left with this suspicion, that the `my ($param1, $param2 ...) = @_;` pattern is *bad* for performance reasons. So I find I have to choose between fast and readable programs which is, well, an impossible choice.

I end up writing subs where performance is the focus with `$_[<n>]` and everything else with the pattern above. Trouble is, often I don't know beforehand where the bottlenecks are ;-)

Is there a way to get named parameters that are also fast? Or what seems to be canon on the matter? `$_[0]` or `$bar`?

## Appendix: Speed demo

```
use Time::HiRes qw(time);

# Lets just do *something* with the parameters - here we just add up all
# their lengths
my $totalLength = 0;

sub foo1 {
    # Access $_[0] directly - effectively call-by-reference
    $totalLength += length($_[0]);
}

sub foo2 {
    # Access a copy of $_[0] - effectively call-by-value  - involves
    # copying
    my ($bar) = @_;
    $totalLength += length($bar);
}

my $a = 'b' x 10_000;
my $t0 = time;
foreach (0..1_000_000) {
    foo1($a);
}
printf "foo1 %2.6f\n", time - $t0;

$t0 = time;
foreach (0..1_000_000) {
    foo2($a);
}
printf "foo2 %2.6f\n", time - $t0;
```

Prints out

```
foo1 0.329470
foo2 1.280364
```

foo1 is almost 4 times faster than foo2 because it avoids copying `$_[0]`.

Comment: but comparing foo1/foo2 is also pointless, you are only looking at the overhead here. For a sufficiently large function this overhead can be ignored. If your function is really small like foo1/foo2 then you shouldn't have a function in the first place.

Comment: A valid point. I did make a speed demo that really made the difference _visible_. And it lost realism in the process.

Comment: Choose readable over fast...

Comment: subroutine calls are "*bad* for performance reasons", too.  nevertheless, it is almost always a good idea to use subroutines.

Comment: The benchmark is probably missing the line `use Time::HiRes qw(time);`?

Comment: I rarely (I.e. never) find myself passing 10k strings millions of times. Is this benchmark realistic?

Comment: By the way `my $bar = shift` seems to be slightly faster than `my ($bar) = @_`.

Comment: If you want performance, write it in assembler. All high-level languages are slower than it. Perl is no about performance. It's about making the easy things easy and the difficult things possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass them via a hashref:

```
my %args = (bar=>1, baz=>2);
mySub(\%args);
sub mySub {
    my $args = shift;
    doSomething($args); # pass entire parameter list for cheap!
    doSomething2($args{bar}); # Use specific parameter
}
```

Frankly, I have my slight doubts about the performance benefits (hash access isn't free) but you can benchmark it if you really need to. But this isn't the best performance option (see below) and may not even be needed (see last part), and this I don't see much need to try.

---

Another option (which kinda sucks but is better for performance) is to use `$_[1]` etc... but combat non-readability via extensive comments.

```
           # pass `baz`
doSomething($_[1]);
```

---

Another even-higher-performance-but-bad-design option is to bypass the parameter passing alltogether, and use global variables to pass parameters.

```
our $bar = 1;
mySub();
sub mySub {
    #do something with $bar. Pray some other code didn't clobber it
}
```

---

Last consideration:

If your code is so well-tuned AND so performance-sensitive that copying a couple of scalars makes a significant difference, you **MAY want to drop out of Perl into pure C for those functions**.

But, as Knuth said, **please don't optimize prematurely**.

**First, [profile your entire app](http://p3rl.org/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf)** and make sure that the scalar parameter copying is indeed where your biggest bottlenecks are. I don't dispute that this is plausible, but typically, bottlenecks are elsewhere (IO, DB, slow data structures, etc...).

In other words, the fact that `$operation_X` can be implemented 4 times faster, means nothing if `$operation_X` takes up a total of 0.01% of your runtime. Speeding it up by a factor of 4 is simply not worth the trouble given decreased readability.

Comment: You may be able to play some aliasing tricks as well, but as I never used them, not sure of performance.

Comment: Yeah, I also use the hashref approach, but for subs with one or two parameters, that becomes ugly for the caller, as in e.g. `myEncode({str=>"foo"])` vs. `myEncode("foo")`. But it does answer the question...

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch - for a sub with 1 or 2 parameters, using the second approach may be readable enough. Ugly as hell, but if performance is THAT critical... Then again, if your code is so well-tuned AND so performance-sensitive that copying a couple of scalars makes a difference, you MAY want to drop out of Perl into pure C for those functions.

Comment: +1: the operation_X discussion is to the point, we need to be pragmatic.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it pretty much confirms the approach I've taken so far. I just had a suspicion that copying all parameters to all subs throughout my app could take substantially more than %0.01 of run time.

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch - count how many calls you make to each sub, and write a test driver to make that many calls with that many parameters and no other work. Then change the test driver to use $_[0] etc.. and compare benchmarks.

Comment: FWIW, the last time (many years ago) that I benchmarked `foo( bar => 'baz' )` vs. `foo( { bar => 'baz' } )`, the non-hashref version was slightly faster.

Comment: @friedo: maybe faster, but doesn't avoid the copy

Comment: @ysth - wouldn't the "avoids the copy" depend on what the sub does with $_[1]?

Comment: @DVK: I was presuming `%hash=@_`; not sure what the point would be of making the parameters look named but actually using them positionally

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're passing $bar and $baz, in that order, to sub do_something(), another bad option is to use the following scary -- but documented -- syntax:

```
sub foo1 { goto &do_something}
```

...which would pass the context on to do_something() immediately. No help with documenting the parameters, but it's possibly the fastest pass-on-to-another-routine mechanism of the bunch. :-)

Heck, I'd downvote this answer myself....

Comment: As an alternative/equivalent to this, I'd use the properly documented `sub foo1 { &do_something; }` syntax instead - same result but not so scary...

Comment: ? both are documented; they differ in whether foo1 or foo1's caller is considered to be the caller of do_something.